# In Scala reflection, what is a "type site"?

Tags: scala, reflection, type-signature

There are a few methods in the Scala reflection API that require a `site` parameter, the meaning of which is undocumented. For example, [Symbol.typeSignatureIn](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$Symbol@typeSignatureIn(site:Symbols.this.Type):Symbols.this.Type) takes such a parameter. What does it mean?

I got the phrase “type site” from the brief documentation under [Symbol.infoIn](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$Symbol@infoIn(site:Symbols.this.Type):Symbols.this.Type).